# Why does the quadcopter become unstable after turning?

Tags: quadcopter, ros, gazebo

I'm trying to write a simple test `MAVROS` node where my quadrotor is expected to go in a straight line and then have 180-degree turn and come back and land on where it initially took off.
The issue that I'm facing now is, if I suddenly change the yaw, it shocks the quadrotor (creates quiet a bit of turbulence) and thus I want to have as smooth of a turn as possible.
So for this I thought, maybe hovering in the last position for a couple of iterations would do the trick. However, I noticed after adding this snippet, the drone flies unstably, shakes badly and the last turn before landing, seems to not to take place properly as well!

What am I missing here?
Here are two video clips I recorded 1 shows the quadrotor with my `loiter_fn`(hover in place for some iterations before changing the yaw), and the other without it.

Clip1 : https://files.fm/f/4ts4b4kdv
Clip2: https://files.fm/f/687gmhj6d
and here is my code :

````cpp
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/CommandBool.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/SetMode.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/State.h>
#include <tf/LinearMath/Quaternion.h>

// https://docs.px4.io/master/en/simulation/ros_interface.html

mavros_msgs::State current_state;

void state_cb(const mavros_msgs::State::ConstPtr &msg)
{
    current_state = *msg;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "offb_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    ros::Subscriber state_sub = nh.subscribe<mavros_msgs::State>("mavros/state", 10, state_cb);
    ros::Publisher local_pos_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("mavros/setpoint_position/local", 10);
    ros::ServiceClient arming_client = nh.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::CommandBool>("mavros/cmd/arming");
    ros::ServiceClient set_mode_client = nh.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::SetMode>("mavros/set_mode");

    // The setpoint publishing rate MUST be faster than 2Hz
    ros::Rate rate(20.0);

    // Wait for FCU connection
    while (ros::ok() && !current_state.connected)
    {
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }

    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;
    pose.pose.position.x = 0; 
    pose.pose.position.y = 0;
    pose.pose.position.z = 0;

    auto to_degree = [](const double &radian_angle)
    {
        return radian_angle * (180 / 3.14);
    };
    auto to_radian = [](const double &degree_angle)
    {
        return (degree_angle * 3.14) / 180;
    };

    tf::Quaternion qtr;
    float yaw = to_radian(180.0);
    qtr.setRPY(0, 0, yaw);
    pose.pose.orientation.w = qtr.getW();
    pose.pose.orientation.x = qtr.getX();
    pose.pose.orientation.y = qtr.getY();
    pose.pose.orientation.z = qtr.getZ();

    // Send a few setpoints before starting
    for (int i = 100; ros::ok() && i > 0; --i)
    {
        local_pos_pub.publish(pose);
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }

    mavros_msgs::SetMode offb_set_mode;
    offb_set_mode.request.custom_mode = "OFFBOARD";

    mavros_msgs::CommandBool arm_cmd;
    arm_cmd.request.value = true;

    ros::Time last_request = ros::Time::now();

    bool land = false;
    int i = 0;
    int starting_point = 0;
    float angles[] = {180.0, 360.0};

    // Hovers inplace for 'counter' iterations
    auto loiter_fn = [&](const int& wait_counter)
    {
        pose.pose.orientation.x = 1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < wait_counter; i++)
        {
            local_pos_pub.publish(pose);
        }
    };

        // Changes the yaw
    auto change_yaw_angle = [&](const float &angle_degree, const int& wait_counter=5)
    {
        loiter_fn(wait_counter);
        qtr.setRPY(0, 0, to_radian(angle_degree));
        pose.pose.orientation.w = qtr.getW();
        pose.pose.orientation.x = qtr.getX();
        pose.pose.orientation.y = qtr.getY();
        pose.pose.orientation.z = qtr.getZ();
    };
    
    
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        if (current_state.mode != "OFFBOARD" && (ros::Time::now() - last_request > ros::Duration(5.0))) 
        {
            if (set_mode_client.call(offb_set_mode) && offb_set_mode.response.mode_sent)
            {
                ROS_INFO("Offboard enabled");
                std::cout << "Offboard enabled!\n";
                starting_point = i;
            }

            std::cout << "current_state.mode: " << current_state.mode << std::endl;

            last_request = ros::Time::now();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!current_state.armed && (ros::Time::now() - last_request > ros::Duration(5.0))) //5
            {
                if (arming_client.call(arm_cmd) && arm_cmd.response.success)
                {
                    ROS_INFO("Vehicle armed");
                    std::cout << "Vehicle armed!\n";
                }
                last_request = ros::Time::now();
            }
        }

        std::cout << "status: " << current_state.mode << " " << i << "\n";
        if (current_state.mode == "OFFBOARD")
        {
            pose.pose.position.x = i;
            pose.pose.position.y = 0;
            auto z = pose.pose.position.z;
            pose.pose.position.z = z < 30 ? 0.5 * i : 30;
            pose.pose.orientation.x = 5;

            if (i > starting_point + 400)
            {
                change_yaw_angle(180);
                // since counter is not a good measure, we have to manually set an 
                // offset that resembles home
                pose.pose.position.x = -(i - (starting_point + 552));
                std::cout << "status(returning): " << current_state.mode << " x: " << pose.pose.position.x << "\n";
                if (i == 800)
                {
                    change_yaw_angle(360);
                    land = true;
                }
            }
        }

        i++;
        // Important Note
        // This line is a must have, before switching to offboard, we must have already sent
        // a queue of positions. here we are already in a loop. so we can publish the previous location
        // what ever it is (it will hover on that specific location) until the pose is updated.
        local_pos_pub.publish(pose);

        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();

        if (land)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use `setpoint_velocity` to turn. When you use `position_setpoints` then the drone will try to accelerate then decelerate causing this disturbance. By sending `cmd_vel` setpoints you can have a smooth turn and then you can publish your return setpoint.

Topic name.
`/mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel`
Message [docs](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistStamped.html).